A question on geometric quantization
Assume $(M,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold. Consider $H$ to be the space of complex wavefunctions on $M$, $\{ \psi: M\to \mathbb{C}\}$ with scalar product given by $\langle \psi |\phi \rangle =\int_{M}d\mu \langle \psi (q)|\phi (q)\rangle$ where $\mu$ is the Liouville volume form.
To define a linear correspondense between classical and quantum observables, one can use the Hamiltonian vector fields: $$F\mapsto \hat{F}=-i\hbar \xi_{F}-\langle \theta ,\xi_{F}\rangle +F$$ where $F\in C^{\infty}(M)$, $\omega =-d\theta$ and $\xi_F =\omega^{\sharp}dF=\lbrace \cdot ,F\rbrace$.
My question is that how $\hat{F}$ acts on $H$? For an element $\psi\in H$ (which is a complex function), $\xi_F (\psi)=\lbrace \psi,F\rbrace$ but this is not the case becuase $\lbrace \cdot ,\cdot \rbrace :C^{\infty}(M)\times C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\psi \not \in C^{\infty}(M)$.
Moreover, when we want to get $[‎‎\widehat{F},‎‎\widehat{G}]=i\hbar‎‎\widehat{\lbrace F,G\rbrace}$, we face to $[\xi_F ,G]$. What does this mean? This Lie bracket is related to vector fields while $G$ is just a member of $C^{\infty}(M)$. I have trouble with proving $[‎‎\widehat{F},‎‎\widehat{G}]=i\hbar‎‎\widehat{\lbrace F,G\rbrace}$.

The answer to your question about how to apply differential operators to non-smooth functions is exactly the same as the one I provided here - you define it on a dense subset of the Hilbert space. If you want to learn about the technicalities of it, take a look at Section IV here, which describes how it works for the momentum operator $-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. You can also consult pretty much any book on the functional analysis of unbounded operators, e.g. "Functional Analysis" by Reed and Simon.
To answer your second question, for linear operators $A, B$ on $\mathcal{H}$, $[A,B]$ is the linear operator given by
$$
[A,B]\psi := A(B\psi) - B(A\psi).
$$
What about this are you having trouble understanding? The operator $G$ is really "multiplication by $G$", i.e. $(G\psi)(x) = G(x)\psi(x)$.
